# How to map a Map<String, int[]>?

Tags: java, hibernate

Is it possible to map the data structure `Map<String, int[]>` using hibernate? The array will allways have the same number entries.

Sorry for the possibly dumb question but I have currently no idea how to do this.

Comment: What's the meaning of the numbers in those int[4]s? This looks like you actually want a new class with 4 fields.

Comment: The array will store target values of a measurement mapped on steps of a development process. For example in level 0 the value should be 2, at level 1 it should be 5 would result in [0]=2 and [1]=5. The string stores the name of the measurement.

I have to correct myself. The number of the steps is constant but configurable ==> so we need an array or a list. In our test configuration we use 4.

My only idea is to implement a class with the string and the array as members and map this class separately. But is there a more elegant way?

Comment: A class like `Measurement { String name; int[] data; }` would be more "relational" then `Map<String, int[]>` here, but it would complicate access by name -- what's the usual access pattern? If there's more than the "expected value" coming in the foreseeable future, maybe `Measurement { String name; SortedSet<DataPoint> data; } class DataPoint { int value; ... }` might be another (quite verbose) option.

Comment: I implemented the mapping as an own class with a string and a list of Integers as members. Thanks for your hint :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to do something similar some time ago and even after some severe literature research I was not able to find a way of mapping arrays in hibernate in a generic way.

My solution at that time was a wrapping class with (much more than 4) fields and accessor methods which would allow array-like access to those fields.

```
int a;
int b;
int c;
int d;

public int get(int ref) {
   switch(ref) {
     case 0:
       return a;
     case 1:
       return b;
     case 2:
       return c;
     case 3:
       return d;
     default:
       throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
  }
}
```

If you have significantly more than four variables to take care of, you can use reflection instead of the switch statement.